# In R, how do I choose specific rows in a data frame that does not have a specified name?

Tags: r

For example, I have a vector of characters with rownames that I do not want. How can I remove all rows in a data frame that contain these names?

I tried the following, but they do not work:

```
highRisk <- sortedClinical[-rownames(lowRisk),]
```

and

```
highRisk <- sortedClinical[!rownames(lowRisk),]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data.frame that we can read in (use `dput` or create a small "identical" data.frame).

Comment: `highRisk<-sortedClinical[!rownames(sortedClinical) %in% lowrisk,]` should work. Though sample data via `dput` is always best.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. The total number of rows in sortedClinical is equal to that of highRisk, but the rows of highRisk and lowRisk should add up to nrow(sortedClinical)

Comment: Did you change `lowrisk` to `lowRisk`? I forgot to capitalize it in my previous comment.

Comment: Try `highRisk <- sortedClinical[!(rownames(sortedClinical) %in% rownames (lowrisk)),] ` But, as already said, please dput your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how to achieve this (it's one of several ways):

```
# Define a dataframe, give it rownames and define a vector of unwanted rownames
mydf <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("a","b","c"))
rownames(mydf) <- c("First", "Second", "Third")
unwanted.rows <- c("First", "Third")

# Do the subsetting using setdiff()
mydf[setdiff(rownames(mydf),unwanted.rows),]

##        a b
## Second 2 b
```

So **for your situation**, you would use:

```
highRisk <- sortedClinical[setdiff(rownames(sortedClinical),rownames(lowRisk)),]
```